# Get a substring of the current node in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <TopLevel>
    <Payments>
      <PaymentID>PID1</PaymentID>
      <Transaction>
        <TransID>TR1-PID1XX</TransID>
        <TransNumber>1</TransNumber>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
        <TransID>TR1-PID1XY</TransID>
        <TransNumber>2</TransNumber>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
        <TransID>TR1-PID1XX</TransID>
        <TransNumber>3</TransNumber>
      </Transaction>
    </Payments>
    <Payments>
      <PaymentID>PID2</PaymentID>
      <Transaction>
        <TransID>TR2-PID2XY</TransID>
        <TransNumber>4</TransNumber>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
        <TransID>TR2-PID2XX</TransID>
        <TransNumber>5</TransNumber>
      </Transaction>
      <Transaction>
        <TransID>TR2-PID2XY</TransID>
        <TransNumber>6</TransNumber>
      </Transaction>
    </Payments>
  </TopLevel>
</Document>
```

And this is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="Transaction">
    <Transaction>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="TransID"/>
    </Transaction>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TransID">
    <TransID>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </TransID>
    <TransNumber>
      <xsl:number level="any"/>
    </TransNumber>
    <xsl:if test="substring(//TransID,9,2)='XX'">
      <TransCode>
        <xsl:value-of select ="substring(//TransID,1,3)"/>
      </TransCode>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

My XSLT is not picking up the current node substring, but instead is always getting the first nodes string, anything i missed here?

By the way here is my desired output:

```
<Payments>
  <PaymentID>PID1</PaymentID>
  <Transaction>
    <TransID>TR1-PID1XX</TransID>
    <TransNumber>1</TransNumber>
    <TransCode>TR11</TransCode>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction>
    <TransID>TR1-PID1XY</TransID>
    <TransNumber>2</TransNumber>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction>
    <TransID>TR1-PID1XX</TransID>
    <TransNumber>3</TransNumber>
    <TransCode>TR13</TransCode>
  </Transaction>
</Payments>
<Payments>
  <PaymentID>PID2</PaymentID>
  <Transaction>
    <TransID>TR2-PID2XY</TransID>
    <TransNumber>4</TransNumber>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction>
    <TransID>TR2-PID2XX</TransID>
    <TransNumber>5</TransNumber>
    <TransCode>TR25</TransCode>
  </Transaction>
  <Transaction>
    <TransID>TR2-PID2XY</TransID>
    <TransNumber>6</TransNumber>
  </Transaction>
</Payments>
```

Thanks to all for this wonderful community :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you are always searching for all `TransID` nodes in the whole document. Plus, as a `substring` on a node-set will operate against the first node in the set its always looking at the first node.

Change it to the below and it should work fine.

```
<xsl:if test="substring(./text(),9,2)='XX'">
  <TransCode>
    <xsl:value-of select ="substring(./text(),1,3)"/>
  </TransCode>
</xsl:if>
```